# cannot make the image disappear on a jpanel

Tags: java, swing

I'm struggling with this issue. I want to make an image on a panel disappear by pressing a button and setting a flag in the button listener to do this. The key boolean variable is showImage which I hoped would prevent loading the image. It seems that I cannot create a new image from the butoon listener.
    package com.pumpfundamentals.calc;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import com.pumpfundamentals.calc.CalcVel;



public class Calc extends JFrame{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6408828418879466758L;
    //private static final String imageURL = null;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel, panel3;
    private JButton buttonCalc, buttonView;
    private JLabel labelDia, labelFlow, labelVel, labelVelRes, labelRe, labelReRes;
    private JLabel labelFrict_par, labelFrict_parRes, labelFrict_fact, labelFrict_factRes;
    private JTextField diaInput, flowInput;

    public double v, dia, fl, re, f_par, fr_100, f_fact, eps=0.00015, v_round;
    public  boolean showImage = false;

    public Image vel_formula = null;

    private static BufferedImage image = null;
    private JLabel labelImage;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new Calc("img/vel_formula.png");
        }
        });
    }

    public Calc(String fileName) {

        this.setSize(1000, 800);
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Pipe friction calculations");


        //frame = new JFrame();
        //panel = new JPanel();
        JPanel btnPanel  = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());

        //Box theBox = Box.createHorizontalBox();

        //panel3 = new JPanel();
        //panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //frame.add(panel);
        buttonView = new JButton("VIEW");
        buttonCalc = new JButton("CALC");
        labelDia = new JLabel("  Dia.  ");
        diaInput = new JTextField(5);
        diaInput.setText("0");
        labelFlow = new JLabel("  flow  ");
        flowInput = new JTextField(5);
        flowInput.setText("0");
        labelVel = new JLabel("  velocity (ft/s)  ");
        labelVelRes = new JLabel("___");
        labelVelRes.setForeground(Color.red);
        labelRe = new JLabel("  Re no.  ");
        labelReRes = new JLabel("___");
        labelReRes.setForeground(Color.red);
        labelFrict_par = new JLabel("  frict.param.  ");
        labelFrict_parRes = new JLabel("___");
        labelFrict_parRes.setForeground(Color.red);

        labelFrict_fact = new JLabel("  frict. fact. (ft/100 ft)  ");
        labelFrict_factRes = new JLabel("___");
        labelFrict_factRes.setForeground(Color.red);

        btnPanel.add(buttonView);
        btnPanel.add(buttonCalc);
        btnPanel.add(labelDia);
        btnPanel.add(diaInput);
        btnPanel.add(labelFlow);
        btnPanel.add(flowInput);
        btnPanel.add(labelVel);
        btnPanel.add(labelVelRes);
        btnPanel.add(labelRe);
        btnPanel.add(labelReRes);
        btnPanel.add(labelFrict_par);
        btnPanel.add(labelFrict_parRes);
        btnPanel.add(labelFrict_fact);
        btnPanel.add(labelFrict_factRes);

        //buttonPanel.add(theBox);
        //this.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);


        //this.add(new ImageArea(fileName), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ImageArea image = new ImageArea(fileName);

        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        cp.add(image, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        cp.add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        ListenForButton lForButton = new ListenForButton();
        buttonCalc.addActionListener(lForButton);
        buttonView.addActionListener(lForButton);
        //this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("serial")
    private class ImageArea extends JPanel{

        public ImageArea(String fileName) {

            try {
                image = ImageIO.read(new File(fileName));
                //System.out.println(showImage + " 3");
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            //boolean show = false;
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            System.out.println(showImage + " 1");
            if(showImage) g2.drawImage(image, 0, 10, 577, 743, null);
            /*
            if(!showImage) {
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            g2.fillRect(0, 10, 800, 440);
            }


            */
        }

    }

    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(e.getSource() == buttonCalc) {
                CalcVel vel = new CalcVel();
                v = vel.CalcVel(diaInput.getText(), flowInput.getText());
                labelVelRes.setText("  " + v);
                CalcRe rey = new CalcRe();
                re = rey.CalcRe(v, diaInput.getText());
                DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.000E0");
                String reString = df.format(re).toLowerCase();
                labelReRes.setText("  " + reString);
                CalcFrict_par f_param = new CalcFrict_par();
                f_par = f_param.CalcFrict_par(eps, diaInput.getText(), re);
                labelFrict_parRes.setText("  " + f_par);
                CalcFrictFact f_fac = new CalcFrictFact();
                f_fact = f_fac.CalcFrictFact(f_par, v, diaInput.getText());
                labelFrict_factRes.setText("  " + f_fact);

            }
            else if(e.getSource() == buttonView) {
                //System.out.println("img/vel_formula.png");
                showImage = true;

                System.out.println(showImage + " 2");
                ImageArea image = new ImageArea("img/vel_formula.png");


            }
        }

    }



}
```

Comment: After `showImage = true;` call `repaint` on the `ImageArea`, but you will need a reference to the instance which is currently displayed

Comment: I would also recommend having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) to get a better understanding of how painting works in Swing

Answer (score 1):

To be honest ur code is a mess. I ran your code and there is no image showing whats so ever. Instead of creating your nested ImageArea class, you just put your image into a Label.

```
 labelImage = new JLabel();
 labelImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(fileName));
 this.add(labelImage); // not sure in what panel you add the image
```

Later when you press the button you do the following:

```
else if (e.getSource() == buttonView)
    {
        // inverting the boolean
        showImage = !showImage;
        // setting the image visible or not
        labelImage.setVisible(showImage);
    }
}
```

So you dont need to repaint anything.

If you provide the full code including the CalcVel Class and making sure that the image is showing, I can try to help you more specifically.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, it now works with FredK's advice. CalcVel class and all those other classes' just return a double, they all work, and the image loads properly. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

In a subclass of JPanel, you should not override the paint() method.
You should instead override the paintComponent() method, and the first statement in that should be a call to super.paintComponent().